# Retrieve comments and replies with Koala gem

Tags: ruby, koala

maybe this is stupid question, but how to retrieve comments and their replies (last 50) from Facebook profile page? 
For example: `api.get_connections("depechemode","posts")` (or `feed`) give me only comments. Do I really have to create another request for every comment to get its replies? Is there better way to obtain all responses (comments + replies) from posts?

I tried FQL with "googled" examples, but without success...

UPDATE: I can get comments+replies from post with `api.get_connections(post_id,"comments", :filter="stream")` but is there any other option? It will be nice to get posts+comments+replies with one request...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer to myself:

`graph.get_connections("askdotcom", "posts", :fields=>"message,id,created_time,comments.fields(comments.fields(from,message),message,from),from")`

Just had to play with [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Comment: this works with me too.but it returns the data in array containing nested hash. how can i retrive the message and its respective comments only?